# graph database: why we need it?

Tags: database, nosql, graph-databases

I have read graph database from wikipedia, and still don't understand.

What is "index-free adjacency"?

Can I take it as "instead of store the primary key to the rows of other table, it directly store the physical position of those rows"

Answer (score 1):

Graph database is usable when your data can be represented as graph (route on the map, some tree, etc). These databases provide you cool functions to work with storage as with graph. I really don't know, why one can use this kind of db for something else.

Answer (score 0):

In a Graph Data Base you have references to the other "object" or whatever, so you do not need to join tables (that is more expensive in CPU & memory terms).